# Sort file based on date in file name

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort files with respect to their date in the file name. I have written code which sorts the files but not running as expected.

Code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Sorting {

    public static void displayFiles(File[] files) {
        for (File f : files) {
             System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File folder = new File("C:\\source");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, getFileComparator());

        displayFiles(listOfFiles);
    }

     protected static Comparator<File> getFileComparator() {
        Comparator<File> fileComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                String o1Date = o1.getName().substring(o1.getName().lastIndexOf("_"));
                String o2Date = o2.getName().substring(o2.getName().lastIndexOf("_"));
                return o1Date.compareTo(o2Date);
            }
        };

        return fileComparator;
    }
}
```

My files are :

```
abc_2018_11_30.dat
abc_2018_11_30-0002.dat
file_2015_09_28.dat
hi_2015_09_28.dat
xxx_2015_09_28.dat
xyz_ca_2015_09_28.dat
```

I need output as :

```
file_2015_09_28.dat
hi_2015_09_28.dat
xxx_2015_09_28.dat
xyz_ca_2015_09_28.dat
abc_2018_11_30.dat
abc_2018_11_30-0002.dat
```

Files with -001,-002...so on should come after actual file in sequence. But my code giving output as :

```
file_2015_09_28.dat
hi_2015_09_28.dat
xxx_2015_09_28.dat
xyz_ca_2015_09_28.dat
abc_2018_11_30-0002.dat
abc_2018_11_30.dat
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: you also need to compare your -001,-002....

Comment: Using getName().lastIndexOf("_") means you will only compare based on day of month, not the year, month, and day of month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace below line:

```
return o1Date.compareTo(o2Date);
```

with

```
return o1Date.replace("-", "_").compareTo(o2Date.replace("-", "_"));
```

But this will just sort files on day and not on date. The more accurate way is to extract date with regular expression and perform comparison. Below is the code:

```
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(".*_([0-9_]{10}.*)\\..*");
    public static String extractDate(String in)
     {
         Matcher m=pattern.matcher(in);
         if(m.matches())
            return m.group(1);

         return in;
     }
```

and return statement will be:

```
return extractDate(o1.getName()).compareTo(extractDate(o2.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth. Use regex to extract the part you want to compare and compare only this. Your order does not work because '.' comes before '_'.

```
static Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(".*_([0-9_]{10}.*)\\..*");

public static String extractDate(String in)
{
    Matcher m=pattern.matcher(in);
    if(m.matches())
        return m.group(1);
    return in;
}
```

In the comparator:

```
return extractDate(o1.getName()).compareTo(extractDate(o2.getName());
```

Comment: Hi Conffusion, Thanks for the reply. This solution is also working fine.

Comment: This is the right way to perform comparison on such data. So I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

Design a class for your files. Include reference to the `File`, date as a `LocalDate` and serial number. Implement `Comparable` comparing first on date, then on serial number.

Construct an object for each file. Use a regular expression to take out the date and the serial number. Parse the date and the number. Set serial number to -1 if there isn’t one in the file name.

Sort your objects. Take out the files from the sorted result.

It can probably be done in fewer code lines without the class and with a good `Comparator.comparing(…)` if you prefer and performance isn’t critical.